# Processing array of json objects in node.js in non blocking way

Tags: node.js, event-loop

is there a way to process a long array of json objects (parse json for each array item for instance) in a way that does not block the event loop?

It tried:

Example

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

let arr = []

// fill in the array with sample data
for (let index = 0; index < 300000; index++) {
    arr.push( [  { ...500 lines of json ...}   ])
    
}

app.get('/map', (req, res) => {
         arr.map(a => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))) //some example of json operation
  res.send('Hello map')
})

//this will not run until the previous map is finished, in other words, app.get('/map') call will block event loop

app.get('/something', (req, res) => {
        res.send('Hello something')
 })
 
   
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

When I call `http://localhost:3000/map` I will not be able to get results of `http://localhost:3000/something` till the first one finishes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With CPU intensive task in nodeJS, you should use `cluster`. See more [here](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)

The below code is example in your case:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const data = require('./data');
const cluster = require('cluster');
const {cpus} = require('os');

let arr = []

// fill in the array with sample data
for (let index = 0; index < 300000; index++) {
    arr.push(data)
}

app.get('/map', (req, res) => {
    arr.map(a => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))); //some example of json operation
    res.send('Hello map')
})

//this will not run until the previous map is finished, in other words, app.get('/map') call will block event loop

app.get('/something', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello something')
})


const numCPUs = cpus().length;
const clt = cluster;

if (clt.isPrimary) {
    console.log(`Master server started on ${process.pid}`);
    for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        clt.fork();
    }
    clt.on('online', (worker) => {
        console.log('Worker %s is online', worker.process.pid);
    });
    clt.on('exit', (worker) => {
        console.log(`Worker ${worker.process.pid} died. Restarting`);
        clt.fork();
    });
} else {
    console.log(`Cluster server started on ${process.pid}`);
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
    })
}
```

File `data.js` contain your json data.

Comment: Thanks, Is there a guarantee that my request will not end up in the same instance?

Comment: No, for that you should use a reverse proxy. I recommend PM2 with nginx reverse proxy.

Comment: I also tried to use workers but it seems a bad idea if I transfer data to them and back.

Comment: cluster help your server don't block request, if cpu handle heavy task and block i/o. But when handle large data json, you should use stream json. Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json